# A particular example of crossover in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I would like to make this crossover example for a genetic algorithm. Can you help me? I can't make the vertical red line and the arrow.
[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}%

\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{red}
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
\hline
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\cellcolor{yellow}1&\cellcolor{yellow}1&\cellcolor{yellow}1&\cellcolor{yellow}1&\cellcolor{red}1&\cellcolor{red}1&\cellcolor{red}1&\cellcolor{red}1\\
\hline

\end{tabular} \tabularnewline

\end{tabular}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}%

\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{yellow}
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
\hline
\end{tabular} &

\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\cellcolor{red}1&\cellcolor{red}1&\cellcolor{red}1&\cellcolor{red}1&\cellcolor{yellow}1&\cellcolor{yellow}1&\cellcolor{yellow}1&\cellcolor{yellow}1\\
\hline

\end{tabular} \tabularnewline
\bigskip

\end{tabular}
```

I did this
[image]

Comment: That's a nice start. Can you describe your problem more precisely? (Where do you have difficulties? To set the numbers? Or the red mark?...)

Comment: I would like to write parents under the first two tables
and children under the others. 
I can't make the vertical red line and the arrow.

Comment: I think what you need is not a tabular environment but the `tikz`package which allows you to make drawings

Comment: Any news? Does any of answers is not candidate to be accepted?

Answer (score 2):

One more suggestion with use of the `tikz` package. Using `matrix` library, defining styles for fill colors the MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} %  enable drawing in LaTeX
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                matrix,
                positioning}% To enable regular polygon node style

\begin{document}
\noindent%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm,
  MTRX/.style = {matrix of nodes,
                 nodes={draw, minimum size=5.6mm, anchor=center,
                        inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
                 column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                 row sep=2mm},
    CR/.style = {fill=red},  %fill  Color Red
    CY/.style = {fill=yellow}%fill  Color Yellow
                        ] 
% left table
\matrix  (m1) [MTRX,
               row 1/.append style = {nodes={CR}},
               row 2/.append style = {nodes={CY}},
               label=below: parent
               ] 
{
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9   \\
5 & 8 & 9 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 5 & 8   \\
};
% right table
\matrix  (m2) [MTRX, right=of m1,
               label=below:child
               ]
{
  |[CR]| 0 & |[CR]| 1 & |[CR]| 2 & |[CR]| 3 & |[CR]| 4
& |[CY]| 5 & |[CY]| 6 & |[CY]| 7 & |[CY]| 8 & |[CY]| 9   \\
  |[CY]| 5 & |[CY]| 8 & |[CY]| 9 & |[CY]| 4 & |[CY]| 2
& |[CR]| 3 & |[CR]| 5 & |[CR]| 7 & |[CR]| 5 & |[CR]| 8   \\
};
\draw[very thick, blue] (m1.north) -- (m1.south);
\draw[double, -{Implies[]}, semithick] (m1.east) -- (m2.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
(teal lines indicate text borders)

Note:

- You not provide any information about  your document layout. If you like to have larger or smaller cell size, accordingly change `minimum size` in `nodes` definition. In MWE selected `minimum size=5.6mm`  is determined by trial.
- Colors of cells are the same as are used in code fragment i the question. You can simple change in definition of `CR` and `CY` styles

**Edit:** added are labels to both matrices (parent, child)

Comment: This is much neater than my code!

Comment: @JuCa, thank you very much for compliment. :-)

Comment: @Zarko, another thing. Is it possibile write under the first matrix a) parents and under second matrix b) child?

Comment: @Cirino, yes, it is possible. See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks @Zarko. Chapeau!

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using `tikz`package.

First, I defined square nodes, then a macro `NbrSquare` drawing a square node with 3 arguments: the node coordinates, the node fill color and the text in the node.

When adjusting the scale factor, the square node `minimum size` also need to be adjusted to keep proportionality.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}% To enable drawing in LaTeX
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}% To enable regular polygon node style

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,
     square/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4, minimum size=1.2cm}]% To define square nodes
    
    \newcommand{\NbrSquare}[3]{% To draw square nodes at a given position, filled with a color, and containing some centered text
        \node at (#1) [square, draw, fill=#2] {#3};
    }
    
    % The top line on the left, all nodes are same colors, numbers in order
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9}
    {
        \NbrSquare{\x,0}{green}{\x};
    }

    % The bottom line on the left
    \NbrSquare{0,-1.5}{cyan}{5};
    \NbrSquare{1,-1.5}{cyan}{8};
    \NbrSquare{2,-1.5}{cyan}{9};
    \NbrSquare{3,-1.5}{cyan}{4};
    \NbrSquare{4,-1.5}{cyan}{2};
    \NbrSquare{5,-1.5}{cyan}{3};
    \NbrSquare{6,-1.5}{cyan}{5};
    \NbrSquare{7,-1.5}{cyan}{7};
    \NbrSquare{8,-1.5}{cyan}{8};
    \NbrSquare{9,-1.5}{cyan}{8};

    % To draw a vertical line on the left side
    \draw [red, line width=5pt] (4.5,-2.5) -- ++ (0,3.5);

    % To draw an arrow between left and right sides
    \draw[->, very thick] (10,-0.75) -- ++(1,0);

    % Top line on the right side
    \NbrSquare{12,0}{cyan}{0};
    \NbrSquare{13,0}{cyan}{1};
    \NbrSquare{14,0}{cyan}{2};
    \NbrSquare{15,0}{cyan}{3};
    \NbrSquare{16,0}{cyan}{4};
    \NbrSquare{17,0}{cyan}{3};
    \NbrSquare{18,0}{cyan}{5};
    \NbrSquare{19,0}{cyan}{7};
    \NbrSquare{20,0}{cyan}{5};
    \NbrSquare{21,0}{cyan}{8};

    % Bottom line on the left side
    \NbrSquare{12,-1.5}{cyan}{5};
    \NbrSquare{13,-1.5}{cyan}{8};
    \NbrSquare{14,-1.5}{cyan}{9};
    \NbrSquare{15,-1.5}{cyan}{4};
    \NbrSquare{16,-1.5}{cyan}{2};
    \NbrSquare{17,-1.5}{green}{5};
    \NbrSquare{18,-1.5}{green}{6};
    \NbrSquare{19,-1.5}{green}{7};
    \NbrSquare{20,-1.5}{green}{8};
    \NbrSquare{21,-1.5}{green}{9};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: can i resize the dimension of polygon? it is too large and not run in A4

Comment: Yes, in the options of the `tikzpicture` environment you can pass the option 'scale=n' with n the scaling factor between 0 and 1. It will scale down the whole picture (n>1 to scale up). I added the scaling factor in the code.

Comment: @Cirino If this answer works for you, you can upvote or accept it. If you need more explanations about it, you can ask in comments.